# SimpleSAML Unable to validate Signature error

Tags: azure, metadata, signature, simplesamlphp, federation

Today, June 23rd, 2022, we are experiencing a mysterious phenomenon that I simply can not see myself out of.

We are a software company where our customers use Azure AD as a login method using SimpleSAML.

This means that these are different websites with different associated Azure ADs.

Today, we have seen that 7 different sites, incl. one of our own, experienced to get the error:

```
SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Caused by: Exception: Unable to validate Signature
```

The above is solved with a refresh of the metadata, and the pages are live again without any problems.
No certificates are due to expire, and the earliest will not expire until 2023.

I can not find any global issue with Microsoft or Azure, and our setup has been working fine for so long, and with the refresh of metadata, it's working again.

Does anyone have any clue on, what could be the issue? It just seems strange that there are 7 different websites, with different Azure setups and different metadata who experience this kind of issue on the same day, within 8 hours of each other.

Beware that we are running a daily cronjob to ensure metadata is refreshed.

[Image of the error from 1 of the sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMtVJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft products automatically perform rollover for their certificates. So it can be that the parties you interfaces with automatically rolled over to new certificates. Refreshing the metadata explains why that solved the problem.

ADFS/AD will have the old and new certificate both in metadata for a while before the old one is invalidated, so periodic refresh should work to keep the service working without downtime.